# How to convert buffered base64 to Tiff image in js?

Tags: javascript, python, typescript

The image is encoded in python as follows:

```
buffered = BytesIO()
croped_image.save(buffered, format="TIFF")img_str = base64.b64encode(buffered.getvalue())
```

and sends that responce:

```
{"image_data": "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"}
```

and, how convert this result to image in javascript(typescript)

Comment: Have a look at the url: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50738924/how-to-covert-base64-encoded-image-to-a-tiff-png-jpeg-using-nodejs/50790749 OR https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30488116/convert-png-base-64-string-to-tiff-base-64-string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert base64 to image in javascript/jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227078/convert-base64-to-image-in-javascript-jquery)

Comment: @SparkFountain I've tried everything.

Comment: @PrasadWargad does not work